# Data is passed within ""(doublequotes) from angularJs to SpringMVC Controller

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, angularjs-scope

I am passing data from controller.js to service.js to SpringController.java

but weird thing is happening when i pass $scope.credentials.uname data to Java Controller .

The data passed is coming in doublequotes . When i print the value in Java 
its getting printed as "USER" instead of USER.

Also due to this i am not able to save the username in database.

```
$scope.submitUsername = function()
        {
            $log.info("username "+$scope.credentials.uname);
```

> Here log is getting printed properly chrome console
>
> username SYS_USER --> without double quotes

```
            loginService.fetchUserType(angular.copy($scope.credentials.uname)).then(function(data)
                {
                    if (data.loginType == 'NotValidUsername') 
                    {
                        $log.info("Failure")
                        toaster.pop('information', "Warning", 'Enter Valid UserName');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $log.info("Success")
                        if (data.loginType == 'database') 
                            {
                                $scope.isExternalUser = true;
                                $scope.showSubmitButton = false;
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                $scope.isExternalUser = false;
                                $scope.showSubmitButton = false;
                            }
                    }
                })


        };
```

**service.js**

```
fetchUserType : function(userName)
        {

            var promise = $http({
                url : "checkUserType.do",
                method : "POST",
                data : JSON.stringify(userName)
            }).success(function(data, status, header, config, statusText)
            {
            }).error(function(data, status, header, config, statusText)
            {
                if(!status === 901)
                    toaster.pop('error', status, statusText);
            }).then(function(response)
            {
                return response.data;
            })
            return promise;
        }
```

**Java Controller method**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/checkUserType.do", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
    @ResponseBody
    public Object checkUserType(@RequestBody String username,HttpServletRequest request)
    {

      log.info(" Inside checkUserType  "+username);
      User user = new User();
      user.setUserName(username);
      String userType =  loginService.checkUserType(user.getUserName());

      user.setLoginType(userType);
      return user;

    }
```

Output on console is

Inside checkUserType "SYS_USER".

How should i pass data so that i can avoid these ""(doublequotes) being passed to Java Controller

Answer (score 0):

Remove `JSON.stringify(userName)` from your service.js This is whats adding the double quotes around your request.

Instead your `data` should just be `data: userName`. When it gets send to your controller it will be correctly converted to json for your controller to digest.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: Thank You . It worked . But i have seen in other modules of same project , they have done JSON.stringify(data), it worked properly without doublequotes, only the data was proper json object eg: - {
"credentials" :{

"uname":"",
"password":""
}
}

Comment: There are some libraries that can strip the double quotes out. I believe setting the content-type in your request as `application/json` might do it too. Not sure